# Can't play this video on android

Tags: android, video, playback

```
package com.thenewboston.videoplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final VideoView adarshsVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.adarshsVideo);
adarshsVideo.setVideoPath("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj0PYv2DIhk");
MediaController m = new MediaController(this);
m.setAnchorView(adarshsVideo);
adarshsVideo.setMediaController(m);
adarshsVideo.start();

}
```

I have included `android.permission.INTERNET` in my manifest. But every time I open the app, it throws the message Can't play this video.

Comment: Go with this tutorial. http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/ this is what you want

Comment: You can use 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView' if you want to play youtube video's. link -http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

Answer (score -1):

There might be many reasons to not play the video. You can test it on other devices also set `android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"` in **manifest file**.
Set the attribute in **Application tag**.
Most of the time,the problem is solved using the hardware acceleration which also helps in animations.
Please see the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10803715)

Comment: I dont know why it is downvoted. The resolution could be by adding the manifest tag attribute. This provides atleast a solution to try for the question asked. Ridiculous

Comment: sorry i cant't explain as it wasn't me who down voted.I only gave a suggestion that's it.No downvote.

Comment: sorry for my language